# squashed sine wave

Tags: compression

[Sinewave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ue17.png)

I'm slightly out of my comfort zone with this one. I need to produce a function for use in an animation, but a sine wave isn't quite right. I tried adding a square wave, but that didn't work either. What think I need is a "squashed" sine wave, or one that is compressed, similar to the blue line in the image above, could anybody tell me what the formula is that I need?

Addition: I need the formula to be a drop-in replacement for sin(x), having the same period and amplitude.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the curve to be periodic and repeat?

Comment: Yes, I should have said that. It should be a drop-in replacement for sin(x), just with an altered shape. I keep thinking I should be multiplying it by something, but I really have very little idea.

Comment: your drawing looks like $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ periodized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try $\sqrt[n]{\sin(x)}$, it should do the trick.  Recommended you use odd values for $n$.

Comment: I guess you meant $|\sin(x)|^a sign(\sin(x))$ with $a = 1/n$

Comment: I just plugged "y=sin(x) ^ ( 1 / 3 )" into the animation and it looks pretty good, I'm quite happy with this, I would like to thank everybody for their help!

Answer (score 0):

HINT

The exponent should be <1 like
$$ | \cos(x)|^ {\frac14}$$
Change / define this function sign in two regions between odd multiples of $\pi/2. $ using $if$